# Excel VBA Color cells inside a table that contains value

Tags: excel, vba

I have one sheet (Sales) with a table (Table1) that looks like this.

[image]

I’m trying to set a specific background color to every third row, except for cells that don’t have a value.
The background color is based on the brand name (in column 2). The color for each brand is stipulated from another sheet (Colors) that looks like this:

[image]

This is the code:

```
Sub Color()
    Set DataCells = Sheets("Sales").Range("Table1[Brand]")
    Set ColorValueCells = Sheets("Colors").Range("Colors[Brand]") 
    For Each datacell In DataCells
        For Each ColorValueCell In ColorValueCells
            If datacell.Value = ColorValueCell.Value Then
                Set ColorIndexCell = Sheets("Colors").Range("C" & ColorValueCell.Row)
                datacell.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = ColorIndexCell.Value
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Call clean_empty_cells
End Sub

Sub clean_empty_cells()
    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = Sheets("Sales").Range("Table1")
    For Each myCell In myrange
        If myCell.Text = "" Then
            myCell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please indicate what this code is doing that is in error and on which line the error happens.

Comment: Why not just use conditional formatting?

Answer (score 1):

I agree that Conditional Formatting would be the easier approach. But if you require VBA and setting the cell color value, this is a possible solution. Let me know if i misudnerstood anything or fi you have any additional questions.

```
Option Explicit

Sub ColorRows()

Dim count, i As Long

''Count # of rows in table
count = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

''Declare what row # the first row of data starts within the table
i = 2


Do While i <= count
''Where 2 represents the column number to match values
''Change the RGB value for each IF statement accordingly
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Levi's" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Interior.Color = RGB(67, 195, 233)
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Vans" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Interior.Color = RGB(67, 195, 233)
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = "Calvin Klein" Then
        Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, 7)).Interior.Color = RGB(67, 195, 233)
    End If
i = i + 1

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: The challenge is that the table contain over 50 brands right now, and new brand will be added frequently.So I would prefer to just be able to add a Brand and Color to the list, instead of having to alter the code every time a brand is added.